# Summary of a frame based on formula

Tags: r, aggregate

Consider the following:

```
df = data.frame(x=1:10, y = (1:10) %% 2 == 0)
```

I would like to call something like

```
summarize(x ~ y, data = df)
```

and get an output like

```
       FALSE TRUE
Mean   5     6
Count  5     5
```

Basically, I want something like `xtabs` but with a customizable output. E.g. `xtabs(x ~ y, data = df, FUN = c(mean, length))`.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `aggregate` in base R, but there are *many* options available. With `aggregate`, you'll have to do a little bit of work to get things just right, but here's the basic idea:

```
> aggregate(x ~ y, df, function(x) cbind(mean(x), length(x)))
      y x.1 x.2
1 FALSE   5   5
2  TRUE   6   5
```

To get you started with alternatives, here's "data.table":

```
> library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(df)
> DT[, list(Mean = mean(x), Count = length(x)), by = "y"]
       y Mean Count
1: FALSE    5     5
2:  TRUE    6     5
```

And plyr:

```
> library(plyr)
> ddply(df, .(y), summarize, Mean = mean(x), Count = length(x))
      y Mean Count
1 FALSE    5     5
2  TRUE    6     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the tables package, it lets you designate the shape, style, and summary measures of a table all in the formula statement.  If you use a formula like:

```
group + (n=1) ~ (var1 + var2)*(mean+sd)
```

Then you will get a table with a row for each level of `group` and a total row at the bottom then the columns will be the mean and standard deviations of `var1` and `var2` (total of 4 columns).

There are additional options that can be used to format the columns and headers, you can use your own created functions to do the summaries, you can do counts and percentages, and lots of other things.